# Alchemy DataNews fake news?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, alchemyapi

got this entry in a query

```
{
 "id": "MTc4MzcwNTQ4fDE0NDM1MjYyNDg",
 "source": {
   "enriched": {
     "url": {
       "enrichedTitle": {
         "docSentiment": {
           "mixed": "0",
           "score": -0.56943202,
           "type": "negative"
         }
       },
       "publicationDate": {
         "date": "20151028T000000",
         "confident": "false"
       },
       "title": "Deloitte and IBM Watson bring Cognitive Analytics to SA | IT News Africa- Africa\u0027s Technology News Leader"
     }
   }
 },
 "timestamp": 1443526248
},
```

It seems the date is set to the future (October 28th, 2015)

What kind of data is that?

Comment: I would say that is a bug or a parse error. It seems to refer to this news message: http://www.itnewsafrica.com/2015/09/deloitte-and-ibm-watson-bring-cognitive-analytics-to-sa/

Comment: I can't find the feed to check where the error comes from

Comment: Hey leo can you take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `confident` field. If is false; then, the `publicationDate` could be wrong. Try to use the `timestamp` field, at least that will tell you when the document was ingested.